Поиск алгоритма сопоставления прохода геозон и маршрута в режиме онлайн
Ищу алгоритм для сопоставления маршрута, который состоит из набора геозон, и массива событий прохода геозон, в режиме онлайн.
При этом в какие-то геозоны маршрута объект мог не попасть. Плюс маршрут маятниковый и может иметь одинаковые зоны как в прямом, так и в обратном направлении. Из-за этого может быть сложно понять - объект уже движется в обратном направлении не дойдя до конца прямого направления или всё ещё продолжает движение в прямом направлении.
Наверняка кто-то уже сталкивался с такой проблемой. Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, что можно почитать на эту тему.

Не очень понятно, что за геозоны, что за события. Если вопрос об оптимальном маршруте между точками, но наверняка тут что то про графы должно быть

@tym42167, нет маршрут заранее определен. Оптимизировать его не нужно. Маршрут представляет собой обычно два направления с одинаковым или различным набором геозон (полигонов). События - это вход и выход в/из геозоны. Некоторые геозоны маршрута могут быть пропущены, из-за некорректно работающей геолокации. В нормальной ситуации объект должен посещать зоны по порядку.
